# Delete key from registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, registry, windows-7-x64

I want to make uninstaller which should delete registry key from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Problem is that every time when i try delete location get `LASTERROR 2`, which is usually wrong name.

```
HKEY hKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
LSTATUS deletes = SHDeleteKey(hKey, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\NameOfApp\\");
if (deletes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return true;
}
```

I have same code in C# which work, but C++ not. Also try as administrator, still nothing (with C# didn't put any special privileges and work).

OS: Windows 7, 64 bit.

Do you have any idea, what is happening?

Comment: Which OS you are using and how do you compile the `c++` program?

Comment: @user0815 windows 7 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 64-bit Windows there are two separated registry trees. One for 32-bit applications and the other for 64-bit ones. It depends on your application (32-bit vs 64-bit) which tree is used when calling `SHDeleteKey` and that could be why it is working with `c#` but not with `c++`.

You can use [RegDeleteKeyEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to explicitly define the tree you want to access.

Comment: Thxn man :) you save my day !!!! (long laster = RegDeleteKeyEx(hKey, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\NameOfApp\\", KEY_WOW64_64KEY, 0);)